# Install OpenCV 2.4.7 in Windows 7 for any editor

Tags: c++, opencv

I have problem with installing OpenCV under Windows 7 x64. Following [this](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html). Downloaded executable and ran it. But I do not see any bin folder, instead there are 2 folders: **build** and **source**. What to do next I do not know, what to include to system path and how? 
**Note:**
I am not using visual c++, instead I use devcpp editor.

Comment: Next: you download Cmake and run it in the source folder. This *may* be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779617/compiling-opencv-2-3-1-programs-with-mingw-gcc-g-on-windows-7-64bit.

Answer (score -1):

The OpenCV windows installer comes as a self-extraction program. It essentially packs everything including the source files, docs, and most importantly, the pre-compiled files.

The pre-compiled files are located in `build`, and sources files are located in `source`. If you are intented to use opencv libraries solely, all you need to do is to

1. add `build/include/` into your IDE additional include list.
2. selectively add `build/lib/..` into the additional link list according to your vs version.
3. add `build/bin/` to your system PATH, so your program can find them.

Comment: *according to your vs version* - @torayeff specifically said they weren't using VS.  Also your path is incorrect, it would be `build\x64\vc11\bin` if using VS2012, e.g. However with DevCpp presumably a build from source is needed. That is time consuming but not hard (at least that is the case with VS)

Comment: there is no build/lib and build/bin, in build folder there are only: include, OpenCVConfig.cmake, OpenCVConfig-version.cmake, doc, java, python, x64/vc10, x86/vc10, x64/vc11, x86/vc11. I can not find any bin folder.

Comment: @B... Why I can not just include source files and build applications? Or are there already generated dll files?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. Please check the directory on your machine.

Comment: @richard.g I did not understand you?

Comment: @torayeff , they should be located in the sub folders like `x86/vc10` according to the compiler.

Comment: @richard.g but they are for visual c++, can I use them with any other C++ IDE like devcpp

Comment: @torayeff I don't know, maybe you can try. If it doesn't work, try to compile it from source. Sorry I can't help you.

Comment: DevCpp uses different name mangling schemes, different exception handling, etc so visual studio libraries won't work with it. Different versions of VS even require different libraries see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996076/can-c-libraries-compiled-with-vc10-sp1-be-linked-by-code-compiled-with-vc11 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979859/can-i-create-dll-with-vc-2008-and-use-it-in-vc-6/9984668#9984668.  If you can't find a devcpp build of the libraries you will have to build them yourself, or use VS (VS Express is free, and if you are a student you can get full VS too).